# Error: Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside NavigationContainer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, react-navigation

I went through the other answers to this question but none has worked for me i'm trying to do a button in the LoginScreen that navigates to the RegisterScreen but get the error

This is what my App.js returns

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <StatusBar hidden />

        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Login">
          <Stack.Screen name ="Login" component={LoginScreen}/>
          <Stack.Screen name ="Register" component={RegisterScreen}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>

        <Tab.Navigator
          activeColor="black"
          inactiveColor="gray"
          initialRouteName="Home"
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: "",
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={33} />
              ),
            }}
          />

          <Tab.Screen
            name="Calendrier"
            component={Calendrier}
            options={{
              tabBarLabel: "",
              tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="calendar-month-outline"
                  color={color}
                  size={30}
                />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

And this is where is want to use the navigation.navigate but get the error (line 2)

```
export default function LoginScreen ()  {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return(
    <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'mistyrose'}}>
               <View style={{justifyContent:'flex-start', alignItems:"flex-end"}}>
    <Button color ='mistyrose' onPress={()=> navigation.navigate("Register")} title='abaabab'></Button>
</View>
            
            <ConnectButton/>
        </View>
```

I tried using export default fuction LoginScreen({navigation}){
//code... } but it didn't work either, I checked my imports and i'm pretty sure they're the good ones. Please Help!!

Comment: What error do you get when using `function LoginScreen({navigation})` ?

Comment: I get : `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'navigate') ` when i click on the button

Comment: Did you get the same error when trying to access `navigation` prop in `Home` screen?

Comment: Thnak you i tried this and i got a more desciptive error and now it is fixed thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad I was able to help (somehow) ... just curious to know what was the issue?

Comment: I take back what I said it still doesn't work and i got the same  error

Comment: Create an expo `snack`, I'm sure that 'dhelp figuring out the issue...

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@docmundovg/stackoverflow-error-react-navigation

Comment: It's right here my friend, `const logged = false
  if (logged!= true){
    return <LoginScreen/>; 
  }` ... `navigation` object is onlly available when a screen rendered as a part of `navigator` ... and here's it's been rendered as standalone screen...

Comment: Thanks you soo much i got stuck on a dumb error like this for 2h